# Playing an HTTP audio stream on an HTTPS site without warnings

Tags: browser, https

In a site that otherwise fully uses HTTPS, I'm playing a HTTP radio stream using the `<audio>` element. This causes the browser to show a warning sign in the address bar that unsecure elements are present in the page.

I tried putting the `<audio>` inside an `<iframe>`, but at least Chrome wasn't fooled that easily.

The radio stream is outside my control and not available via HTTPS. I could pipe it through an HTTPS proxy, but that would be costly.

Is there any other way to play the stream without any warnings, in modern browsers? (I'm assuming there isn't, because I'd consider it a bug in that browser.)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. If you did find a way to do what you are asking, you should definitely file a bug report with the browser vendor, as that would be a serious security vulnerability. Not to mention the fact that, should you succeed, informed users would no longer be able to trust the security of your site.